# Does LinearRegression uses Gradient Descent for finding slope and y-intercept of the best fit line?

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I know that **Gradient Descent** is an optimization algorithm used for optimizing the cost of the loss function.

Does Linear Regression model of the `sklearn` package use Gradient Descent ?

Or it simply uses **normal equations** of curve fitting (which I read in my 11th class) to find the slope and the coefficient(s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**, Linear Regression typically uses a method called **Ordinary Least Squares (OLS)** to find the best fit line. OLS minimizes the sum of the squared residuals (the differences between the observed and predicted values) to find the optimal parameters for the regression line.

However, when the dataset is large and cannot fit into memory, or when the problem is a part of a larger optimization problem, variants of Linear Regression such as Stochastic Gradient Descent (SGD) or Mini-Batch Gradient Descent can be used, which are iterative optimization algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html):

> From the implementation point of view, this is just plain Ordinary Least Squares (scipy.linalg.lstsq) or Non Negative Least Squares (scipy.optimize.nnls) wrapped as a predictor object.

So no, it does not perform Gradient Descent.